# How to reference libraries in jdk without hardcoding path in Eclipse project file?

Tags: eclipse, java

How to reference libraries in jdk (not in jre) without hardcoding path in Eclipse project file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use classpath variables (see Window > Prefernces: Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables) in order to add a level of indirection. Choose "Add Variable..." in the project properties dialog to refer to the variable.